# Should there be a [finger-slide] or [legato-slide] tag to differentiate from [slide-guitar]

Tags: discussion, tags, guitars

Today a user posted [How should I do slides on guitar without hurting my fingers?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/how-should-i-do-slides-on-guitar-without-hurting-my-fingers) and tagged it with [slide-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slide-guitar). That tag was later removed, because the question seems to be about legato sliding with the fingers as opposed to using a slide.

On the other hand, I mistakenly re-tagged [How to practice legato slide on the guitar? What constitutes proper technique?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54823/how-to-practice-legato-slide-on-the-guitar-what-constitutes-proper-technique) with [slide-guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slide-guitar) (now fixed).

There are a fair number of questions regarding guitar sliding, some about "slide guitar" and some about "legato", but which are difficult to distinguish for a guitar ignoramus (points to self) or, perhaps, a guitar beginner.

From my perspective, there would be real value in adding a new [guitar-legato](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar-legato) (or some such) to make the distinction explicit. But what does the non-ignoramus community think? Is it always clear from context, even to a beginner? Or does the differentiation have value, if only to make searches more direct?

Comment: Reading that question left me in no doubt that it was nothing to do with *using a slide*. As that doesn't hurt fingers. However, I was uncertain as to its meaning short slides as in legato, or long slides along the string length. 'Slide guitar', thus, is inappropriate as a tag. 'Legato playing' would suffice. Maybe OP didn't understand any more than 'I'm sliding my finger'.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [glissando](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glissando) tag for these questions?  I could see someone debating its use for both fretted and fretless instruments, but Wikipedia includes both discrete and continuous glissando as subsections of glissando, so I think it's fine.

The guitar "sweep" technique could also be considered a glissando, so if you want the tag to exclusively refer to sliding around the strings then this would fail that requirement.

Comment: There's also a [tag:legato] tag, but I think both have a different intended meaning. Still, combined with the [tag:technique] tag it could make sense.

Comment: @Aaron One thing about the legato tag is it doesn't necessarily imply using a slide technique. Hammer-ons and pull-offs are also legato.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Just to clarify, are you also saying that works in favor of the [tag:glissando] tag?

Comment: Glissando isn't an accurate description of sweep-picking. And legato doesn't really imply anything except smooth transition from note to note. Legato *guitar* playing would include pull-off, hammer-on and slide.

Comment: You could play a glissando with the sweep technique though, if you're fast enough.  That's what I meant.